# Print a sub-string containing vowels

Tags: c, substring

I am basically trying to write a function that will return a sub-string containing the vowels in a input string and my function goes something like this:

```
char * get_vow(char *inp_arr,int arr_size);

int main()
{
    char my_arr[7] = "Mahmoud";
    char *result = get_vow(my_arr,7);

    printf("%s", result);
}

char * get_vow(char *inp_arr,int arr_size){
    int i,out_arr_counter = 0;
    char * out_arr;
    for(i = 0;i<arr_size;i++){
    switch(tolower(inp_arr[i])){
            case 'a' :
                *(out_arr+out_arr_counter) = inp_arr[i];
                out_arr_counter++;
                break;
            case 'e' :
                *(out_arr+out_arr_counter) = inp_arr[i];
                out_arr_counter++;
                break;
            case 'i' :
                *(out_arr+out_arr_counter) = inp_arr[i];
                out_arr_counter++;
                break;
            case 'o' :
                *(out_arr+out_arr_counter) = inp_arr[i];
                out_arr_counter++;
                break;
            case 'u' :
                *(out_arr+out_arr_counter) = inp_arr[i];
                out_arr_counter++;
                break;
            default :
                break;
        }
    }
    *(out_arr+out_arr_counter+1) = '\0';
    return out_arr;
 }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't output: **aou** but rather random ASCII values what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to allocate space for out_arr.

Comment: And instead of `*(out_arr + x)` use `out_arr[x]`.

Comment: `*(out_arr+out_arr_counter+1) = '\0';` - there is one space which is uninitialized.

Comment: @cleblanc by allocating space you mean setting an initial address ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you never allocated space for `out_arr`, you need to allocate it with `malloc()`.

You're also off by 1 when you assign the null terminator, because `out_arr_counter` has already been incremented in the loop.

And since all your switch cases do the same thing, you can combine them.

```
char * get_vow(char *inp_arr,int arr_size){
    int i,out_arr_counter = 0;
    char * out_arr = malloc(arr_size + 1);
    for(i = 0;i<arr_size;i++){
        switch(tolower(inp_arr[i])){
        case 'a' :
        case 'e' :
        case 'i' :
        case 'o' :
        case 'u' :
            out_arr[out_arr_counter++] = inp_arr[i];
            break;
        default :
            break;
        }
    }
    out_arr[out_arr_counter] = '\0';
    return out_arr;
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you this was indeed by problem and it solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `out_arr` is uninitialized.

You have two solutions available to you:

- initialize `out_arr` to a dynamically allocated block of memory, or
- Take `out_arr` as a pointer to pre-allocated storage from the caller

The first choice would require the caller to `free` the result; the second choice would let caller pass pointers to local storage, and avoid dynamic allocation altogether.

**Note:** All cases in your `switch` do the same thing, so you could combine their code, like this:

```
switch(tolower(inp_arr[i])){
    case 'a' :
    case 'e' :
    case 'i' :
    case 'o' :
    case 'u' :
        out_arr[out_arr_counter++] = inp_arr[i];
        break;
}
```

Also note the use of index expression `out_arr[out_arr_counter]` in place of pointer dereference expression. This produces a more consistent code.

Comment: Yes in fact that was my problem, thank you for pointing out the dereference part because I always had a feeling one of them won't work at sometime but it seems that it always does do the job, thanks @dasblinkenlight !